# Any way to check for Sudo/Administrator in .NET Standard 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

In .NET Framework, I would check for something like this:

```
(new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())).IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)
```

I've now started targeting projects using .NET Standard 2.0 which doesn't have `WindowsPrincipal` or `WindowsIdentity` in it - it would seem.

What's the right way to check if the process was run with Sudo/Administrator?

Comment: [It does too have `WindowsPrincipal`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Security.Principal.Windows/4.5.0-preview1-26216-02). That approach still only works on Windows, I should think.

Comment: You cannot put all stuffs in .NET Standard projects yet. Try to move such platform dependent items up to the platform specific projects. Design patterns such as IoC can help.

Comment: @JeroenMostert any docs on how to conditionally use it? I have an 
`if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform != PlatformID.Win32NT || (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT && (new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())).IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)))`
but still get: `FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Principal.Windows`

Comment: How are you testing that? If you've installed the package, `System.Security.Principal.Windows` will be available as a runtime assembly. Of course, on Unix platforms the methods will throw `PlatformNotSupportedException` if you try to invoke them. Verify you're using .NET Core 2.0; publish your project first if necessary.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I installed the package with the dotnet cli, then tried to build my code after changing the target framework to .NET Standard 2.0. It threw that error, so I tried a dotnet restore, tried a dotnet clean, and even tried deleting the bin/obj directory manually. All with no luck :(

Comment: The PlatformNotSupportedException is fine - that should never throw based on the if statement I supplied.

Comment: I asked because I can't reproduce it. It "works for me" (on Windows), with a regular .NET Core 2.0 project and using the NuGet package. The `dotnet publish` will end up with the `System.Security.Principal.Windows` assembly in the proper spot, and I get no exceptions about the assembly not being found. If it doesn't work for you (whether on Windows or another platform) there may be a problem with how the implementation assemblies are located.

Comment: That could be it. Tried on macOS and had no luck fetching the needed assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference other packages that offer .NET Standard assets from a .NET Standard 2.0 library. This means you should be able to add a reference to the package @JeroenMostert mentions: `System.Security.Principal.Windows` and you should be able to use it.

The caveat is that the code will only run on Windows. If you are consuming it from a .NET Core 2.0 application and run it on Windows, the code should work.

If it doesn't, please file an issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/new

Comment: I can also have this in code that runs on Unix and Linux, right? So long as I either handle the exception or don't allow that particular snippet to execute?

Comment: Yes. The code will run and throw on non-Windows. Catching the exception and handling it is the right path forward.